# Find the tangent bundle

Tags: smooth-manifolds, tangent-bundle

I've got $\mathbb{R}$ and set $M=\mathbb{Q} \subset \mathbb{R}$. I need to find a tangent bundle $T_{x}M$ at any point $x\in\mathbb{Q}$.
For given $M \subset X$ - normed space, $h \in X$ - tangent vector for $M$ at point $x$ if $\exists \varepsilon >0$ and the map $r(t)$, $t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ so that $x+th+r(t) \in M$ $\forall t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $\frac{\Vert r(t)\Vert}{t}\to0$. So if $h \in \mathbb{Q}$, it's still hard for me to understand how $r(t)$ should look... for irrational the same thing..

Comment: What is the topology on $M$? Is it really a manifold?

Comment: This definition doesn require topology on M, I think. I mean norm is generated by standard euclidean metric

Comment: A manifold is a topological space to start with.... (The problem is, if you use the subspace topology, that $M$ cannot be given the structure of a manifold)

Comment: $M$ is not a Manifold in the definition. This definition is generalization of default tangent vector
We are working with just normed spaces